# join in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Table One

r_c_id  r_id    Cat_id
22      34      67
23      34      68
24      34      69
25      34      70


Table Two

pc_id   pcd_name
67      abc
68      AC
69      dC
70      aa
```

how to get name and Cat_id and pcd_name

currently i am using

```
SELECT * FROM `rcat` WHERE r_id = '34'
```

how to extend my query with join

Comment: This is one of the most basic joins. Please show what you tried.

Comment: Read the manual first (you know the keywords), then do your best to use the new knowledge. (hint: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: public function getProductCategoryById($id) {
        $where = array(
            "product_category_id = ?" => $id
        );
        $result = $this->_db_table->fetchRow($where);
//        print_r($result);die;
        if (!$result) {

            return false;
        }
        $product_category = new Application_Model_ProductCategories($result);
        return $product_category;
    }

how to add distinct in it

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.r_id = table2.pc_id 
WHERE table1.r_id = '34'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 a, table2 b WHERE a.cat_id = b.pc_id AND a.r_id = '34';
```

Answer (score 0):

Even you did not mention about join fields and not matching any field name in both tables but as per data your join should be based on cat_id and pc_id, so you can try below query-

```
SELECT t1.cat_id, t2.pcd_name  
FROM table1 as t1  
JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.cat_id = t2.pc_id 
WHERE t1.r_id = '34'
```